# Call matalab application exe using C#

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

I want to call/run matlab exe from C# code.

I am able to run matlab application exe (Independently) and generate **csv** but if I integrate with C# and call/run matalb application exe and I am getting this error:

> Could not find version 9.4 of the MATALAB Euntim.Attempting.....

Please help me.

My Code (Referred stackoverflow):

```
private void LoadMatApp() {
    string WorkDirectory = @ "C:\matlabApplication";

    var cvsProcessor = new Process {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() {
            FileName = Path.Combine(WorkDirectory, "MatAppGetCSV.exe"),
            WorkingDirectory = WorkDirectory,
            CreateNoWindow = false,
            //WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true    
        }
    };
    cvsProcessor.Start();
    cvsProcessor.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: Try to set `UseShellExecute` to `true`.

Comment: @Andrey : I tried it but got exception {"The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to redirect IO streams."}.

Comment: try to remove IO streams redirecting for now as well. Just try to make it work.

Comment: @Andrey: Tried but same error :(

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-function-from-c-client.html

Comment: @sachin then the only possibility I see that you are calling the wrong exe file. I suggest you triple check that it is the same one. Print your `FileName` to console and try to call it manually. @jrook solution is better in a long run.